# Delphi how to check if cached dataset is same as database dataset with CachedUpdates

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm using a TFDQuery component directly connected with a table on a MySQL database with TFDConnection. I have CachedUpdates at true, so I have to use `ApplyUpdates` / `CommitUpdates` to set the changes into the database.

**I need to know how to check if the data in the buffer are different from the data in the database**, so I can show a MessageDlg to the user to ask him, if he click the X - Close form button:

> "Save changes?"
>
> [Yes][No][Cancel]

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't just [UpdatesPending](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.UpdatesPending) be enough? It indicates that the dataset has been modified on client side. It doesn't check the current data state in database. Pesonally, I would expect such dialog when I modify data on client side, even when someone else commited the same changes before me.

Comment: Oh thank you, that's what i was looking for